# Array of objects in JSON response is received as single object when the array contains one element only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am sending back in the response an array of objects from my resource, and when the array contains only one element I cannot loop the array because the response turns out to be a single object instead of array containing one object.

having this code from the front end side:

```
function loadContent(sUsername, sPath){
    arrayContentBeans = new Array();
    var sUrl = "http://localhost:8080/crosscloudservice/services/RDF/retrieveContent?username="+sUsername+"&path="+sPath;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: sUrl,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function parse(resp, status, xhr) {
           $("#message").html("STATUS: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + "\n" + resp);
           $("#message").hide();
           $.each(resp, function() {
                $.each(this, function(i, cb) {
                    arrayContentBeans.push(cb);
                });
           });

           renderContent();
        },
        error: function(resp, status, xhr){
            $("#message").html("ERROR: " + resp.status + " " + resp.statusText + "\n" + xhr);
            $("#message").show();
        }
    });
}
```

Anyone can tell me how to force JSON to have an array even when it contains one single object?

**UPDATE 1**

Here is the Resource:

```
@GET
    @XmlElement(name = "contentbean")
    @Path("/retrieveContent")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<ContentBean> retrieve(@QueryParam("username") String Username, @QueryParam("path") String Path) {
        ContentBean oContentBean = buildResult(Username, Path);
        List<ContentBean> lContentBeans = new ArrayList<ContentBean>();
        lContentBeans.add(oContentBean);
        return lContentBeans;
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

I've added what should serialize my array now `jackson-core-2.2.3.jar` and the following tag in my web.xml:

```
<init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>org.qcri.crosscloud.ws;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
</init-param>
```

But no luck, it still behaves the same :( any ideas?

Comment: The problem isn't JSON. JSON has no problem with arrays with only one entry. The problem is in whatever code is *producing* the JSON; apparently, it's not producing an array when there's only one object.

Comment: An array with a single element should still be rendered as an array - can we see the code that is generating the JSON, thats is probably where the problem lies.

Comment: I updated my question with the code generating the array. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are sending an Array of object then make sure that when there is only one element to send serialize it as Array so the client side will always get same data structure